# Python versions 3.9.1 and further

Tags: python, package, dependencies, version

At work, the use of Python is highly restricted and I need to

1. use Python 3.9.1 with packages that work fine with 3.9.1
2. download the conda distribution from [this website](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution)

However, the version available from the website is Python 3.9.13 today. In general, will using a newer version of Python (3.9.13) cause any problems in working with packages used in the older version of Python (3.9.1)?

Comment: The feature set should be the same in `3.9.1` and `3.9.13`, but the latest version will most likely have a bunch of bug fixes. Most packages should work fine, though.

Comment: Generally packages on pypi are restricted on the major/minor versions, not the patches. Thats mostly done due to changes to interfaces/expected behavior in the standard library packages. These almost always happen between minor version changes, e.g. 3.8 vs 3.9, and almost never on patch version changes, e.g. 3.9.1 vs 3.9.13